# How to share a folder in the same PC between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, sharing

I need to know if its possible to share a folder, so that I can open the files in it from Ubuntu and Windows.

At the time, I'm using Windows but planning to move back to Ubuntu but my problem would be losing some compatibility that Windows offers when I do college work, and that can be a pain, so my plan is to dual boot and have both OSes. but I don't want to be logged in and out of each OS in order to work or share files.

So is there a way to share folders or files between, lets say, Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7?

Comment: "I need to know if its possible to share a folder" Ubuntu will automatically detect windows partitions and include them for you in Nautilus ("explorer"). No need to do anything for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can read and write on NTFS, so you just have to make such entry in your `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /windows was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=28A139962EFFC093 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

Replace `UUID` with your Windows partition UUID. You can get it by `sudo blkid`:

```
$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for karimov-danil: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="f1b3915e-3c86-a3ec-3273-43967f134ce5" UUID_SUB="f48bf957-6f67-171f-ea75-29ddbd401637" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Win" UUID="28A139962EFFC093" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda3: UUID="571a61fe-6e6f-45d0-9fe1-832f28519f96" TYPE="reiserfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="f1b3915e-3c86-a3ec-3273-43967f134ce5" UUID_SUB="d0318ec5-9e4c-a864-7906-2d43bcbd0374" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0p1: UUID="88dc483f-aef9-454b-b744-2c3e3202a198" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/md0p5: LABEL="Home" UUID="b632fe56-564e-4d3f-833a-fde68fd1dd32" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/md0p6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="da84c996-f7d0-4fe8-8822-407e4f6c5c22" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the Cloud Drive Services avalible out there, DropBox has native support for both OS, even your phone. you should give it a try.

Dropbox you can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, and in windows from their web

Comment: ive considered cloud services, the problem is that i dont always get an internet connection, and personally i would like something more faster

Comment: That is one heck of a workAROUND, to move data from one part of the same HD to another, you first upload the data a noticeable distance around the world, then later download it back to your computer, onto the same hard drive but a different partition a few mm or even microns away... that's thinking way WAY outside the box

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the files stored in ext4 partitions in Windows, you can use [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/), or [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) utilities. Here is a nice little tutorial describing the methods in detail - http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

If you want to access the files stored in FAT/FAT32/NTFS partitions from Ubuntu, just mount the respective partitions and you can access them.